# Generalization of recursive formula

Tags: recursion

Ok, here is the problem, I have formula: $a_n=a_{n-1}+2^{n-4}-a_{n-4}$ with initial variables $a_0=0$, $a_1=0$,$a_2=0$ and $a_3=1$

If not for $2^{n-4}$ member in recursion, I probably would manage to get general form, but $2^{n-4}$ makes things way more complicated.

Is it generally possible to transform $a_n=a_{n-1}+2^{n-4}-a_{n-4}$ into nonrecursive form, and if possible - how?

Comment: Try generating functions.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in my comment above, for such problems (linear recurrences involving tedious terms) the concept of generating functions is useful.
Define $$A(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$$
Now, the recursion implies $a_{n+4}x^n+a_nx^n=a_{n+3}x^n+2^nx^n$.
Summing this over all $n$, we obtain
$$A(x)+\frac{A(x)-x^3}{x^4}=\frac{A(x)}{x^3}+\frac{1}{1-2x}$$
Now, this is a linear equation in $A(x)$ and we can solve for it and obtain
$$A(x)=\frac{x^4-x^3}{(2x-1)(x^4-x+1)}$$
Now, using partial fractions decomposition we can (in principal) reversely obtain the coefficient of $x^n$ in the series of $A(x)$ (which is just $a_n$).
In this way, you can obtain (in principal) a closed form for $a_n$ although (in this case) the partial fractions might become slightly tedious...

Given the non-existence of  nice closed form you might ask for a "nicer" (i.e. homogenous) recursion not involving those terms like $2^{n-4}$ for $a_n$. But this is easily obtained:
We have $a_{n+1}+a_{n+5}-a{n+4}=2^{n+1}=2 \cdot 2^n=2(a_n+a_{n+4}-a_{n+3})$ and hence obtain the homogenous recursion:
$$a_{n+5}=3a_{n+4}-2a_{n+3}-a_{n+1}+2a_n$$
But this is also not useful to compute a closed form using the standard way since the characteristic equation will be $0=x^5-3x^4-2x^3+x-2=(x-2)(x^4-x^3+1)$
where the second factor (similar to the one from our first attempt) is irreducible.

*Remark*: Note that the problems arise only from the irreducibility of the characteristic equation and not really from the $2^{n-4}$ term in the original recurrence since the latter can be easily handled by both approaches.

Comment: I actually wanted to use generating functions and arrived at the same function as yours, but then I was stuck. Just curious, how would you proceed doing partial fractions for this particular case?

Comment: I would not recommend doing so. But technically, you have to factor the fourth-degree polynomial (which is famously possible in terms of root expressions) and then you have to do the standard way. It's just that all the coefficients won't be nice numbers to work with. A computer might do it though...

Comment: Homogenous recursion doesnt really work - correct output is $1, 3, 8, 20, 47, 107, 238, 520, 1121\dots$, but $a_{n}=3a_{n-1}-2a_{n-2}+a_{n-4}+2a_{n-5}$ gives $1, 3, 7, 15, 32, 67, 138, 281, 569\dots$ 



https://cloud.sagemath.com/projects/2132ee9c-442f-437d-bd27-1e1d6a265730/files/4.sagews

Comment: @Tintarn: If you take a look at my solution, you'll see that a different path (inspired by differential equations) reaches the same dead end. (Plus, what if the polynomial had degree larger than $4$, thus precluding explicit solutions by radicals?) I guess we have to declare ourselves satisfied  with less than we wanted.

Comment: @TimoJunolainen: Thanks for your remark! There was a sign error and it should be $-a_{n+1}$ (or $-a_{n-4}$ in your formula). I fixed it..

Comment: @AlexM. Of course, you are completely right. But still I find it useful to present these approaches since they apply to many similar problems and might even work better there ;)

Comment: sequence starts with $1,3,\dots$, other members, lets forget about them, so the next will be $3*3-2*1=9-2=7$, as in $3a_{n+4}+2a_{n+3}+(0)$, but it is 8, not 7.. changing sign on farest member sequence do not help with this.

Comment: @TimoJunolainen: Actually, the non-zero part of the sequence starts with $1,2,\dotsc$ and not $1,3,\dotsc$, or am I just dumb..?

Comment: It is amount of n-bit binaries, that include '111' in them, figured out it is form of fibonacci, figured out how to construct recursive formula for it, and now am curious to turn it to general form

Comment: Well, I was able to get $0, 0, 1, 3, 8, 20, 47, 107, 238, 520, 1121, 2391\dots$, a[n}=3*arr2[n-1]-arr2[n-2]-arr2[n-3]-2*arr2[n-4]

Answer (score 0):

*First method*

Like differential equations, that do not admit a general method to solve them, recursive definitions do not admit general procedures allowing to find the general term. Nevertheless, the one that you post does have an answer, and this is obtained with the Mathematica command

```
RSolve[a[n] == a[n - 1] - a[n - 4] + 2^(n - 4), a[n], n].
```

The solution is the following: let $r_1, r_2, r_3, r_4$ be the complex solutions of the equation $x^4-x^3+1=0$; then $a_n = \frac {2^n} 9 + C_1 r_1 ^n + C_2 r_2 ^n + C_3 r_3 ^n + C_4 r_4 ^n$, where $C_1, C_2, C_3, C_4$ are constants to be found by using the initial conditions, i.e.

$C_1 + C_2 + C_3 + C_4 = -\frac 1 9 \\
C_1 r_1 + C_2 r_2 + C_3 r_3 + C_4 r_4 = -\frac 2 9 \\
C_1 r_1 ^2 + C_2 r_2 ^2 + C_3 r_3 ^2 + C_4 r_4 ^2 = -\frac 4 9 \\
C_1 r_1 ^3 + C_2 r_2 ^3 + C_3 r_3 ^3 + C_4 r_4 ^3 = -\frac 8 9 .$

The determinant of the system will be a Vandermonde determinant, therefore it will have the value $(r_1 - r_2) (r_1 - r_3) (r_1 - r_4) (r_2 - r_3) (r_2 - r_4) (r_3 - r_4)$.

Since $x^4-x^3+1=0$ has degree $4$, its roots can, in principle, be computed explicitly; in practice, though, they look extremely ugly. It is true that sometimes one can perform smart tricks and compute certain polynomials in $r_1, r_2, r_3, r_4$ without explicitly knowing these, by using the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials and patiently computing long algebraic expressions, but I shall not attempt to do it here.

*Second method*

If you are unhappy about using computer software to solve mathematical problems, you could mimic the approach from differential equations.

First, find the general solution of the "homogeneous" equation $a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-4}$. This is done by considering the associated algebraic equation $x^4 = x^3 - 1$; it is known then that $a_n = C_1 r_1 ^n + C_2 r_2 ^n + C_3 r_3 ^n + C_4 r_4 ^n$.

Next, add a particular solution of the "inhomogeneous" equation to the previous expression, to obtain what you are looking for. Since your equation contains an exponential term, why not try it first? Therefore, let us look for a solution of the form $2^n C$. Replacing this in your equation will give you $C = \frac 1 9$.

Finally, impose the initial conditions to find out the 4 constants.

In principle it can be done, in practice the computations will prove intimidating. If you need the result in programming or engineering, you might be satisfied by doing them numerically. If you are doing pure mathematics (i.e. symbolic computations), maybe the above will suffice.

*Third method*

If you are unhappy about the guessing involved in the previous method, call $b_n = 2^n$. Then

$a_n = a_{n-1} -a_{n-4} + b_{n-4} \\
b_n = 2 b_{n-1}.$

Calling $v_n = \left( \begin{array} {c} a_n \\ b_n \end{array} \right)$ gives $v_n = \left( \begin{array} {cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{array} \right) v_{n-1} + \left( \begin{array} {cc} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array} \right) v_{n-4}$, which is a homogeneous vector recursive formula. Again, you may try techniques inspired by those from differential equations, but you will reach the same end, namely the difficulty of working with the roots of the equation $x^4 - x^3 + 1 = 0$.

*Fourth method*

Use generating funtions, as described above in another answer. Again, you will reach the same difficulty related to the associated algebraic equation.

Comment: If to talk about Mathematica RSolve, RSolve[a[n] == a[n - 1] - a[n - 4] + 2^(n - 4), a[n], n]  works, but RSolve[{a[n] == a[n - 1] - a[n - 4] + 2^(n - 4), a[0] = 0, a[1] = 0,   a[2] = 0, a[3] = 1}, a[n], n]..doesnt give any reasonable output. Computational solution is interesting, though Mathematica is bit unfamiliar to me. But anyway, if computational, then computational all the way - tried to follow syntax from https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html, but something is wrong with providing initial state

Comment: @TimoJunolainen: You must use `==` instead of `=`, like in `a[0]==0` and so on. In any case, it won't give you anything usable (I've already tried it), that is why I haven't mentioned this in my answer.